# which kind of html element can be include into an page

Tags: html, include

I want to get all kinds of include in an page,for ex: ,
Now i don't know there was how much kinds of element can be included.
I try to find it with google,but found nothing.
Thank you very much.

Comment: Sorry, but it is unclear what you ask. HTML itself does not have a means to "include" things. It can _reference_ things like pictures, objects. But a real inclusion (for example of further HTML) cannot be done by the (passive) markup itself. You need some logic for that, either `javascript` on the client side, or one of the server side scripting options (for example `php`) to include and then output the HTML.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a great place to start with HTML.
https://www.w3schools.com/html/default.asp
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML